# Rendering FlatList items in a react native modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a FlatList that looks like this. I am trying to make it so that there is a button below my flatlist items and when I click on it, a modal should open and render items from that particular item to the modal.

```
  conditionalHorrorRender() {
    if(this.state.topHorrorLoaded===true) {
        return(
            <View>
            <Modal
                visible={this.state.showModal}
                animationType={'slide'}
                onRequestClose={() => this.closeModalFunc()}
            >
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.original_title}</Text>
                        <Button
                            onPress={() => this.closeModalFunc()}
                            title="Close modal"
                        >
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
                <FlatList
                    onEndReached={this.endreachedboy}
                    horizontal={true}
                    data={this.state.topHorror}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (                    
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.original_title}</Text>
                        <Button
                            onPress={() => this.openModalFunc()}
                            title="Open modal"
                        />
                    </View>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        )

    }
}

openModalFunc() {
  this.setState({showModal: true})
};

closeModalFunc() {
 this.setState({showModal: false})
}
```

At the moment it says `cant find variable: item` and i think it is because I am outside of the scope of the flatlist and it doesnt know what `item` from the flat list is. Where should i render put the  for this to work? Or if i should pass items as props to the modal somehow?

Comment: Is it OK if you add this property of your flatlist? <FlatList .. extraData={this.state} ...>

Comment: Hello, it does not. The modal still gives error `cant find variable: item`